# General algorithm for reading n bits and padding with zeros

Tags: c++, file, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I need a function to read n bits starting from bit x(bit index should start from zero), and if the result is not byte aligned, pad it with zeros. The function will receive `uint8_t` array on the input, and should return `uint8_t` array as well. For example, I have file with following contents:

```
1011 0011 0110 0000
```

Read three bits from the third bit(x=2,n=3); Result:

```
1100 0000
```

There's no (theoretical) limit on input and bit pattern lengths

Comment: You may want to have a look upon the bit shift operators `>>` and `<<`.

Comment: what is your problem? you can post what you already try and explain your error.

Comment: @AchmadJP that's the problem. I couldn't design any solution. I can't find an algorithmic approach.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know about their existence and usage, but they're not the only thing required here. I may need to read >900 bits. How would you then use the shift operators?

Comment: I don't see a way without traversing all the bytes. So if your n = 900, then it is c * 900 / 8 bit operations.

Comment: @HenryLee I don't see the other way as well. But what is the exact procedure for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing such a bitfield extraction efficiently without beyond the direct bit-serial algorithm isn't precisely hard but a tad cumbersome.

Effectively it boils down to an innerloop reading a pair of bytes from the input for each output byte, shifting the resulting word into place based on the source bit-offset, and writing back the upper or lower byte. In addition the final output byte is masked based on the length.

Below is my (poorly-tested) attempt at an implementation:

```
void extract_bitfield(unsigned char *dstptr, const unsigned char *srcptr, size_t bitpos, size_t bitlen) {
    // Skip to the source byte covering the first bit of the range
    srcptr += bitpos / CHAR_BIT;
    // Similarly work out the expected, inclusive, final output byte
    unsigned char *endptr = &dstptr[bitlen / CHAR_BIT];
    // Truncate the bit-positions to offsets within a byte
    bitpos %= CHAR_BIT;
    bitlen %= CHAR_BIT;
    // Scan through and write out a correctly shifted version of every destination byte
    // via an intermediate shifter register
    unsigned long accum = *srcptr++;
    while(dstptr <= endptr) {
        accum = accum << CHAR_BIT | *srcptr++;
        *dstptr++ = accum << bitpos >> CHAR_BIT;
    }
    // Mask out the unwanted LSB bits not covered by the length
    *endptr &= ~(UCHAR_MAX >> bitlen);
}
```

Beware that the code above may read past the end of the source buffer and somewhat messy special handling is required if you can't set up the overhead to allow this. It also assumes `sizeof(long) != 1`.

Of course to get efficiency out of this you will want to use as wide of a native word as possible. However if the target buffer necessarily word-aligned then things get even messier. Furthermore little-endian systems will need byte swizzling fix-ups.

Another subtlety to take heed of is the potential inability to shift a whole word, that is shift counts are frequently interpreted modulo the word length.

Anyway, happy bit-hacking!

Comment: can you show what little-endian fix-up does your code need?

Comment: @assp1r1n3: It doesn't precisely _need_ it. If performance is critical you will want to use a basic type as wide as your architecture/compiler generates efficient code for (most likely 32 or 64-bits, and an accumulator twice as that). In this case since your chosen bit-order appears to be big-endian then to be compatible 8-bit char buffers then generating compatible output will require byte-swapping the input/output through suitable intrinsic functions provided by the compiler. Among other things. Of course if you have the to freedom to select a compatible storage type then this is a non-issue

Comment: your code fails because of invalid memory reads. How to fix this in your solution?

Comment: @assp1r1n3: The best solution is to lay the source buffer so that there is an extra character available as a safety-net. Alternatively you can hoist the final iteration out of the innerloop (`while(dstptr < endptr)`) and conditionally drop the `| *srcptr++` `if(bitlen + bitpos < CHAR_BIT)` if it is unnecessary. There is also the question of how `bitlen = 0` is to be interpreted.

Comment: I did it the easy way(just extra character, no changes to your code), and now it produces invalid output. Yikes!

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's still a bunch of shift and addition operations.

I'll use a slightly larger example to demonstrate this.

Suppose we are give an input of 4 characters, and x = 10, n = 18.

```
00101011 10001001 10101110 01011100
```

First we need to locate the character contains our first bit, by `x / 8`, which gives us 1 (the second character) in this case. We also need the offset in that character, by `x % 8`, which equals to 2.

Now we can get out first character of the solution in three operations.

1. Left shift the second character 10001001 with 2 bits, gives us 00100100.
2. Right shift the third character 10101110 with 6 (comes from `8 - 2`) bits, gives us 00000010.
3. Add these two characters gives us the first character in your return string, gives 00100110.

Loop this routine for `n / 8` rounds. And if `n % 8` is not 0, extract that many bits from the next character, you can do it in many approaches.

So in this example, our second round will give us 10111001, and the last step we get 10, then pad the rest bits with 0s.